# How can I anonymously access (no login) a publicly shared OneDrive folder via the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I have a business OneDrive account with a publicly shared folder (read-only). In a website, I would like to access files in that shared folder without prompting the user to log in (i.e. no authentication).

I have tried using the [OneDrive API Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/direct-endpoint-differences?view=odsp-graph-online) with my request formatted as follows:

```
share_url = "{sharing_url_string}";
var b64 = btoa(share_url);
if (b64[b64.length - 1] === "=")
    b64 = b64.substring(0, b64.length - 1);
var share_id = "u!" + b64.replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "-");
var req_url = "https://{server}/_api/v2.0/shares/" + share_id + "/driveItem?$expand=children"
```

Where `{sharing_url_string}` is the public share string copied from OneDrive's Web UI, and `{server}` is the business OneDrive server (e.g. organization-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_organization_com)

However, I get an error with code = "unauthenticated" and message = "The caller is not authenticated".

Interestingly, if I log into OneDrive in one tab and copy/paste the `req_url` into a new tab, then it seems to work.

Any ideas why it seems to still require authentication even though I have shared the folder publicly?

UPDATE:
I think this has something to do with getting an access token. According to the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), you can get access without a user, but it still requires authentication with a registered app.

I do not have an app, just a link to a public shared folder. This seems to be possible with the Personal OneDrive accounts (see [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454101/access-publicly-shared-onedrive-folder-via-api)). Is it different (not possible) with a Business OneDrive account?

UPDATE 2:
It looks like it may not be possible - looking at their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online) again, way at the bottom under "Remarks" it says: "For OneDrive for Business and SharePoint, the Shares API always requires authentication and cannot be used to access anonymously shared content without a user context."