# How to get to play an audio file in browser itself rather than downloading from a onedrive shared folder link?

Tags: flutter, api, cloud, onedrive

I'm working on a flutter application which uses the shared data from onedrive to play in the app but I'm having trouble getting the m4a file.
For instance, This is a onedrive link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aicuq23aphFzb_KQvr0anumY9Jk?e=NQZfXl. Now, I converted it to an api as given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40471699/8423262) and I got this [URL](https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3UvcyFBaWN1cTIzYXBoRnpiX0tRdnIwYW51bVk5Sms_ZT1OUVpmWGw/root?expand=children). 
When I browse `children.@content.downloadUrl` I see a [link](https://cduxgw.bl.files.1drv.com/y4m7f9zLelSI2vjclq6lcx41wymXT-363cih1GsYy2yOaRDksMtQDaHnbbiCczEh_0AZHISQoSjyOdV-tinpH_wBfpUNFF6fpJ34GAsZVtFAIQ7BQ1D74ia3DGRfgVqSkJnJiBWHh8uPwBYTWML9pEwq_REqASimDlRSbFnH9HCJseNfF8EYrRWdjA5Wvcq_OVJVDwFASc4_smhvDUp5GfO_A) which is a download link but I want a link with m4a file that will play in the browser itself. How am I suppose to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an audio playing service in your app which can take an URL and play it for you handling all the internals like downloading, buffering etc.

Checkout this package: [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)