# Azure Application Unable to access Shared Folder

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, share, onedrive

Guys I am at my wits end!  I am trying to access a shared folder by am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: 
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL2Yvcy
FBdHVBTV9OYWN3VmFoaUZwdU1HU19CaVFDd1d1/root?expand=children` resulted in a 
`403 Forbidden` response: 

{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"The 
    sharing link no longer exists, or you do not have permission to access 
    it."

,"innerError":{"date":"2023-10-11T05:01:49","request-id":"27bd1fc1-
74f8-4d8d-9a43-41a3aa6a9f02","client-request-id":"27bd1fc1-74f8-4d8d-9a43
-41a3aa6a9f02"}}}
```

The share is taken from this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454101/access-publicly-shared-onedrive-folder-via-api) which if you click on the link is very shareable and can be access via a browser, and so *does exist*, so the is no question of lack of access, just that my application is for some reason being denied.

Normally this would be associated with not have the correct permissions, but the token shows that the permissions are part of the `access token` here:

```
      "appid": "563e2470-8b86-48dc-9050-20228336584e",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/74162350-5947-4628-892f-4ee1d28d88cc/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "d9b6b299-ddc2-4708-ac87-2a48beb896f4",
  "rh": "0.AUIAUCMWdEdZKEaJL07h0o2IzAMAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAACkAAA.",
  "roles": [
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Application.Read.All"
  ],
  "sub": "d9b6b299-ddc2-4708-ac87-2a48beb896f4",
  "tenant_region_scope": "OC",
  "tid": "74162350-5947-4628-892f-4ee1d28d88cc",
  "uti": "rJQ_ra77J0ux9XBeCvMIAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "0997a1d0-0d1d-4acb-b408-d5ca73121e90"
  ],
```

And the code segment to access the share is (fails at `->execute`):

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
/*
* If the client requests scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, no consent prompt is shown, regardless of the contents of the client application's registered permissions for Microsoft Graph. The returned token contains the scopes Mail.Read and User.Read.
*/
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL2YvcyFBdHVBTV9OYWN3VmFoaUZwdU1HU19CaVFDd1d1/root?expand=children")
       ->setReturnType(Microsoft\Graph\Model\DriveItem::class)
       ->execute();
```

Comment: Can you add Files.ReadWrite.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All Application permission and try?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Yes, just added both of those and they both appear in the accessToken, but same error.   In fact I began by adding just about every role and then just added what I thought were the essential one.   You can understand why I am pulling my hair out :-)

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/access-denied-shared-folder

Comment: I am able to access the shared folder with same permissions

Comment: Thanks, so there must be something in the application that is stopping it, I have been through the full setup up routine given in the answer step by step.  Did you set up an new application?

Comment: Can you create the new Azure AD application and check whether the shared ID you are passing is correct?

Comment: When you say the shared ID, do you mean the client ID.  If I wasn't I would not get the access token?   Are you using the same code as me?

Comment: I am referring to `$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL2YvcyFBdHVBTV9OYWN3VmFoaUZwdU1HU19CaVFDd1d1/root?expand=children")` the ShareId you are passing here. Please verify that it is valid shared folder ID and **make sure that the shared folder is not deleted**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255588/discussion-between-rukmini-and-alexander).

Comment: Hi @Alexander , were you able to resolve this ? I have been trying to do something similar but with a shared file instead of a folder and getting the same error.

Comment: @YashSethia see my answer below.  If you need me to post the code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a long known problem ([Permission Denied when using Graph API service to call Sharepoint with an Azure AD Guest account](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1039) (image below) and there is no way around the problem without the user consenting to the application's request for permissions.   I have solved the problem by forcing the user to login and to approve the Azure Application, the first time he accesses the page.  Once this is done, then you can use the `Refresh Token` to acquire the necessary `Access Token` to access the user files, without needing to obtain user consent again.

[image: What's App post]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541 and [/help/referencing](/help/referencing), then edit your answer post to fix the problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: According to the [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), to access shared folders either **`Files.ReadWrite.All`** or **`Sites.ReadWrite.All`** API application permission must be granted to the Azure AD application.

Granting **`Sites.Read.All`** permission also will work.

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, **roles** are displayed:

[image]

I shared the folder and copied the sharing URL like below:

[image]

I encoded the Sharing URL:

```cs
string sharingUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/testruk/Eqh5o5j4qqNEqHjy4qK9-dgBoU61RnP3UNj0OVtpuUq0J*****";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');

Console.WriteLine(encodedUrl);
```

[image]

I tried to access the Shared folder using below query and got the **results successfully**:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/ShareID/root?expand=children
```

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Try creating a new Azure AD application and generate the access token.
- Make sure you are passing **correct encoded `ShareID`** in the request.
- Make sure that the sharing link exists, and the shared folder is not deleted.

**Reference:**

[Access Denied error when accessing a shared folder - SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/access-denied-shared-folder)