# Unable to access a Sharepoint File from a publicly shared URL using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to build an application where I want to read the MS Excel file from the "Anyone can view and Edit" URL entered by the user (without signing in). My initial plan was to create an application that uses Microsoft Graph API, store the access token and refresh token, and read the file using the [Accessing shared DriveItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-request-headers) endpoint.

However, when I try to read the file, I am getting the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token has expired or is not yet valid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-10-11T13:51:09",
            "request-id": "2d48cea7-95f2-4be1-80fb-2c8793a66f25",
            "client-request-id": "2d48cea7-95f2-4be1-80fb-2c8793a66f25"
        }
    }
}
```

I have already checked for all the required permissions needed to run this request. From my limited understanding, this error is caused by the fact that the original creator if this file is not in my tenant/organisation because of which I am unable to read his file despite having a publicly shared URL. Is there a way around this through which I can read this file without having to make the user sign in? I am using the graph API for the first time and so my knowledge is limited. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I shared the **One Drive file** publicly like below:

[image]

And shared with the user:

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

I generated **auth code** using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanTID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All
&state=12345
```

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

I **encoded the sharing URL** by using below code:

```cs
string sharingUrl = "SharingURL";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');

Console.WriteLine(encodedUrl);
```

[image]

By using the above access token, **I am able to access the One drive** file:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/SharingID/driveItem
```

[image]

The error "***InvalidAuthenticationToken, Access token has expired or is not yet valid***" usually occurs if the access token you are passing to call the Api is either expired or not valid.

**To resolve the error,** make sure that the access token is not expired by refreshing the access token like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
client_secret:ClientSecret
refresh_token:Refresh_token
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All offline_access
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check whether the user have required permission to access the file:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/ItemID/permissions
```

[image]

Otherwise check if you are able to access the One drive file of your tenant.

If you want to access this file without having to make the user sign in, refer [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77270362/azure-application-unable-to-access-shared-folder?noredirect=1#comment136226361_77270362) by me.

**Reference:**

[Error 403 Forbidden in OneDrive or SharePoint - SharePoint | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/error-403-forbidden)

Comment: Hi @Rukmini Thank you for your answer. I had few questions. The file that you're trying to access, is it created by a user of your own tenant ? If not, whose tenantId are you using while generating the access token ? For my use case, I want to access the file of some other tenant without adding the user to my own tenant as a guest or making him sign in.

Comment: Afaik To access the file the user must be the a guest user